# Find sum of previous n rows in dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe

I want to find the sum of the previous `n` rows in a dataframe. E.g:

```
id = 1:10
vals = c(4,7,2,9,7,0,4,6,1,8)
test = data.frame(id,vals)
```

So, for `n=3`, I'd want to calculate the next column as:

```
test$sum = c(NA, NA, 13,18,18,16,11,10,11,15)
```

The closest I've come is creating a new column using:

```
test$valprevious = c(NA, head(test$vals,-1)
```

Then using a loop to repeat this `n` times, then `sum` across the columns. I'm sure this isn't the most efficient method, are there any functions that access `n` previous rows? Or another way to do this?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can use the `rollsumr` function from the `zoo` package for this:

```
library(zoo)
test$sums <- rollsumr(test$vals, k = 3, fill = NA)
```

which gives:

> ```
> > test
>    id vals sums
> 1   1    4   NA
> 2   2    7   NA
> 3   3    2   13
> 4   4    9   18
> 5   5    7   18
> 6   6    0   16
> 7   7    4   11
> 8   8    6   10
> 9   9    1   11
> 10 10    8   15
> ```

This is the same as using the `rollsum` function with the `align = 'right'` parameter:

```
rollsum(test$vals, k = 3, fill = NA, align = 'right')
```

---

As an alternative, you can use `Reduce` with `shift` from the [data.table](/questions/tagged/data.table) package:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(test)[, sums := Reduce(`+`, shift(vals, 0:2))]
```

which gives the same result:

> ```
> > test
>     id vals sums
>  1:  1    4   NA
>  2:  2    7   NA
>  3:  3    2   13
>  4:  4    9   18
>  5:  5    7   18
>  6:  6    0   16
>  7:  7    4   11
>  8:  8    6   10
>  9:  9    1   11
> 10: 10    8   15
> ```

Recently, fast rolling functions were added to [data.table](/questions/tagged/data.table). Thus, another option would be:

```
setDT(test)[, sums := frollsum(vals, 3)]
```

---

A nice base R alternative as proposed by @alexis_laz in the comments:

```
n <- 3
cs <- cumsum(test$vals)
test$sums <- c(rep_len(NA, n - 1), tail(cs, -(n - 1)) - c(0, head(cs, -n)))
```

---

Another two option as proposed by @Khashaa in the comments:

```
# with base R
n <- 3
test$sums <- c(rep_len(NA, n - 1), rowSums(embed(test$vals, n)))

# with RcppRoll
library(RcppRoll)
test$sums <- roll_sumr(test$vals, 3)
```

---

#### Benchmarks:

As [@alexis_laz noted in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37773356/find-sum-of-previous-n-rows-in-dataframe/37773562#comment63017758_37773562), some of the solutions might create overhead in recalculating sums and re-creating `length`-vectors. This may result in differences in computation speed. As a benchmark on such a small dataset isn't really meaningful, I'll benchmark the different solutions on a large dataset that mimics the example dataset:

```
# window size
n <- 3

# creating functions of the different solutions:
alexis_laz <- function(test) {cs <- cumsum(test$vals); test$sums <- c(rep_len(NA, n - 1), tail(cs, -(n - 1)) - c(0, head(cs, -n)))}
khashaa <- function(test) {test$sums <- c(rep_len(NA, n - 1), rowSums(embed(test$vals, n)))}
rcpp_roll <- function(test) test$sums <- roll_sumr(test$vals, n)
zoo_roll <- function(test) test$sums <- rollsumr(test$vals, k=n, fill=NA)
dt_reduce <- function(test) setDT(test)[, sums := Reduce(`+`, shift(vals, 0:(n-1)))]
dt_froll <- function(test) setDT(test)[, sums := frollsum(vals, n)]

# load the 'bench' package
library(bench)

# create a big test dataset
test <- data.frame(id=rep(1:10,1e7), vals=sample(c(4,7,2,9,7,0,4,6,1,8),1e7,TRUE))

# run the benchmark
big_bm <- mark(alexis_laz(test),
               khashaa(test),
               rcpp_roll(test), 
               zoo_roll(test), 
               dt_reduce(test), 
               dt_froll(test),
               iterations = 1,
               check = FALSE)

# extract some core measures and sort them
big_bm %>% select(expression, median, mem_alloc) %>% arrange(median)
```

which gives:

> ```
>   expression         median mem_alloc
>   <bch:expr>       <bch:tm> <bch:byt>
> 1 dt_froll(test)   776.35ms    1.49GB
> 2 rcpp_roll(test)     1.23s  762.94MB
> 3 dt_reduce(test)     2.12s    4.47GB
> 4 alexis_laz(test)    3.68s    4.47GB
> 5 khashaa(test)       8.35s    5.21GB
> 6 zoo_roll(test)     33.32s   22.63GB
> ```

As you can see, the new `frollsum`-function from the [data.table](/questions/tagged/data.table)-package is the clear winner with regard to speed. When considering memory allocation, `roll_sumr` from [rcpproll](/questions/tagged/rcpproll) needs the least amount of memory.

Comment: An alternative, to avoid recalculating `sum`s and creating `length(vals)` vectors, could be `n = 3; cs = cumsum(test$vals); c(rep_len(NA, n - 1), tail(cs, -(n - 1)) - c(0, head(cs, -n)))`

Comment: @alexis_laz Thx! That is a very nice base R alternative. Added it to the answer.

Comment: `rowSums(embed(test$vals, 3))` used to be the most efficient in pre-`RcppRoll` days.

Comment: @Khashaa nice alternative(s) as well! Added them also.

Comment: A place where the Base implementation by @alexis_laz might fail is when there is missing data in the middle of the vector. Though not perfect, you could modify the base R implementation like this: `lagsum <- function(x, n) { x[is.na(x)] <- 0;  cs <- cumsum(x);  suml <- c(rep_len(NA, n - 1), tail(cs, -(n - 1)) - c(0, head(cs, -n)));  suml[n] <- NA;  suml }`. It simply excludes the NA values from cumsum() by setting them to zero.